# Redisson storing value in hash form

Tags: redis, redisson

When I am trying to use Redisson library it always store data in hash form. Is there anyway I can avoid it if I like

```
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer()
                .setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
        RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
        System.out.println("Config created"+redisson);
        RBucket<String> r=redisson.getBucket("test");
        r.set("value", 1000000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here is how I see the data in Redis

```
127.0.0.1:6379> Get test
"\x03valu\xe5"
```

How can I view the data properly from the redis cli? Or how can I avoid storing the value in hash form completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default Redisson will use Kryo5Codec as codec for all the objects.

If you want to use some other codec, specify the codec while getting redisson objects like below.

```
getRedissonClient().getBucket("test", StringCodec.INSTANCE);
```

For other codecs, [check out this link](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/4.-data-serialization)